# Existentials and reusing witness

Tags: haskell, types, casting, existential-type

Let's imagine I have an existential type T

```
T = ∃X { a :: X,  f :: X -> Int}
```

Of which I produce a value

```
v :: T
v = pack {Int, { a = 0, f x =  0 } } as T
```

So :

- ***users*** of this value are forbidden to know which type `X` is actually used in the implementation. In order to consume this value, their code ***has*** to be polymorphic in `X`
- the implementor, on the other hand, is in full knowledge that `X` is actually an `Int` and can use the capacities of the underlying type as he wishes

I would like to know if there are variant of this mechanism which do not destroy evidence :

```
w, v = pack {Int, { a = 0, f x =  0 } } as T
s = unpack w v  -- recovers type information
```

where `w` would be a value level proof of the type equation tying `X` to `int`. the idea would be to selectively reuse the implementation in another part of the code, and have non polymorphic code. to have the usual existential behaviour, we can just ignore the `w` returned.

I guess one could cast `X` to `Int` and abandon type safety, but that's another story: If I know the secret about `v`, wouldn't it make sense for me to be able to tell the secret to someone else and have the compiler verify that the secret only get used by code it has been given to.

Has it been tried / what's the most wrong part of this?

Answer (score 5):

Use singletons

```
-- singleton for some types we are interested in
data S a where
   Sint  :: S Int
   Sbool :: S Bool

-- existential type, with a singleton inside
data T where
   T :: S a -> a -> (a -> Int) -> T

-- producer
t :: T
t = T Sint 3 succ

-- consumer
foo :: T -> Int
foo (T Sint  n     f) = f (n + 10)
foo (T Sbool True  f) = 23
foo (T Sbool False f) = f 3
```

If you need to go full monty, use `Typeable`.

```
data T where
   T :: Typeable a => a -> (a -> Int) -> T

-- consumer
foo :: T -> Int
foo (T x f) = case cast x of
   Just n  -> f ((n :: Int) + 10)
   Nothing -> 12   -- more casts can be attempted here
```

Answer (score 3):

Pack up a GADT which gives you a way to learn by pattern-matching what the existentially quantified type was. This is a way to emulate a *dependent pair* type.

```
data Ty a where
    IntTy :: Ty Int
    CharTy :: Ty Char

data T = forall a. T {
    ty :: Ty a,
    x :: a,
    f :: a -> Int
}

consumeT :: T -> Int
consumeT (T IntTy x _) = {-# GHC knows (x :: Int) in this branch #-} x + 3
consumeT (T CharTy x f) = {-# GHC knows (x :: Char) in this branch #-} f x + 3
```

Comment: that's a useful middle ground, but the consumer still has to care for all type instantiation through lexical analysis of every case. how about introducing a constraint into scope directly passing it ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I will say that it's possible to make `Ty` values implicit with a hacky class: `class TY a where ty :: Ty a` and `instance TY Int where ty = IntTy`, `instance TY Char where ty = CharTy`. Then if you like you can pack up the implicit `TY` dictionary instead of the explicit `Ty` value: `data T where T :: TY a => { x :: a, f :: a -> Int } -> T`.

Comment: In my example, I statically know in the second line that `v` was produced from an `Int`. I would like to not have to enter some lexical scope by pattern matching to introduce the evidence that X = Int. but that's imposssible in general I guess as w is a value, the compiler would need to execute code to know where w comes from and introduce the corresponding constraints